# What goes in array doesn't match output while looping

Tags: ruby

There is method:

```
possible_queries=[]
variant="tenra"
for i in 0...variant.length
  variant="tenra"
  if variant[i]=~/[\w]/
    letter=variant[i]
    variant[i]="."
    for k in 0...variant.length
      if variant[k]=~/[\w]/ && i!=k
        letter_two=variant[k]
        variant[k]="."
        possible_queries.push(variant)
        print variant+", "
        variant[k]=letter_two
      end
    end
  end
end
print "\n"
print possible_queries.inspect
```

So I send `variant` to array on each inner loop, and print it here for example, but actually `variant` item which is sent to array doesn't match actual array item.

Printed variants:

```
..nra, .e.ra, .en.a, .enr., ..nra, t..ra, t.n.a, t.nr., .e.ra, t..ra, te..a, te.r., .en.a, t.n.a, te..a, ten.., .enr., t.nr., te.r., ten..,
```

And possbile_queries:

```
[".enra", ".enra", ".enra", ".enra", "t.nra", "t.nra", "t.nra", "t.nra", "te.ra", "te.ra", "te.ra", "te.ra", "ten.a", "ten.a", "ten.a", "ten.a", "tenr.", "tenr.", "tenr.", "tenr."]
```

And why is that?

Comment: You should do a little better job at asking. I have no idea, what's wrong with the code, what do you expect and why do you expect that?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, I want simple thing - possible_queries to contain printed varints. And I have no idea, why when i print variant - it is ok, send it to array, and then array items are nothing close to what have been printed before sending

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how the output differs from your expectations, but I'll take a stab and guess that pushing a `.dup`ed string will help:

```
possible_queries.push(variant.dup)
```

That way the changes you make to `variant` after pushing it won't affect what you've already pushed, which seems to be what you expect.

Comment: Thanks man! I thought that if I send before changing variable, it won't affect sent one.

Answer (score 0):

The error is simpler than you may think.. What you're adding to the array in the push is a pointer to the text.. Then my friend you change the contents of the pointer (after you've printed it.

```
  possible_queries.push(variant)   #reference to the object (aka pointer) variant
  print variant+", "               #prints the object (staticly)
  variant[k]=letter_two            #you changed the object variant..  
                                   #the value in the array is still pointing to the object and you've changed its contents.
```

Simple solution.. when you push to the array.. add dup..

```
variant.dup
```